# How can I limit the width of p tags in Bootstrap 4 to make them more readable?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bog standard Bootstrap website. I want to limit the maximum width of the p tags to 34em. If I apply a class to them a set the max-width then the p tags are no longer centred but now left aligned.

Is there a way to set a max width on them and have them stay centred? If I apply it to the div that contains them then the same thing happens.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/westicle/cor2pnm7/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>title</title>
<link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="bg-dark text-light text-center">

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<p class="waffle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you inspected the elements with a browser developer tool to see if the p tags are inheriting any styles; or if the assigned styles are being overwritten?

Comment: Not that I can see. I've stripped it down to the absolute basic and included a fiddle in the question now.

Comment: The simplest method would be to leverage flexbox and add a "justify-content: center" style to your .row class.  https://jsfiddle.net/36svbqah/

Comment: Ah ok, when I apply it more than one paragraph and increase the width of the page it puts the paragraphs side by side. Adding display: inline-block doesn't seem to help.

Comment: If you want to prevent each paragraph from wrapping, then you can put each paragraph into its own row. https://jsfiddle.net/h2Lbaemv/

Comment: Alternatively, if you wanted to keep just one row with multiple paragraphs, then you can use flex-direction: column. https://jsfiddle.net/0esdtumr/

Comment: Free free to mark my answer as the correct one for your question if you feel it has fully answered your question. This will help others be able to easily view the answer quickly to your question.

Comment: flex-direction: column does what I'm looking for now. Thank you.